# Preventing a list overflow in css when a minimum width is reached

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am having trouble with a navigation bar in html. I would like it to be able to adapt to size changes, however when the screen gets really small, the navbar simply overflows and sort of tiles up (I don't know if i'm using the right terminology). I would like it so that when the browser gets really small, it simply goes off the screen rather than tiling up.

I would still like it to be somewhat fluid, however just once this nav bar limit has been reached, simply prevent it from getting smaller.

I've tried applying a `min-width` property, however when I make the screen smaller, the `<li>` elements flow outside of the coloured background.

Here is the jsfiddler:

http://jsfiddle.net/zP4jm/12/

Comment: What exactly is "weird things"? Min-width should be the way to go.

Comment: min-width on the containing div should do the trick.

Comment: added min-width for you. http://jsfiddle.net/zP4jm/16/

Comment: Horizontal scrolling can be annoying especially on a small screen.  why not let the links form a 2nd or 3rd line as the screen  gets smaller?

Comment: @Christoph I don't know what i did, but it doubled everything. Even after testing it on Firefox and Chrome. Everything was doubled.

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes, well because i was building a tutorial based site, I wanted it to be fluid so that people could half the browser size and have another program running, whilst watching. This does seem like a better idea, however it just looks rather odd.

Comment: Does it look odd because the links are flowing outside of the colored background?  or do you prefer to keep the links on a single line? Saying something looks odd does not clarify how to improve the design.  Saying that your prefer a single line is clear and can be dealt with, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Added the min-width on your jsfiddle and works fine.

```
.navmenu{
    height: 45px;
    width: 92%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color:#C60;
    min-width:700px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "overflow: hidden;" to the .navmenu class, so that anything that goes out of bounds will be clipped.

Using the min-width attribute would otherwise work if you'd rather have a scrollbar shown when the window gets too small.

Comment: min-width makes sense but using overflow: hidden can make the page impossible to use.

Comment: @MarcAudet right, for a navigation bar it wouldn't make a lot of sense to use "overflow: hidden", but since the OP mentioned that min-width didn't work for him/her, I thought he might be interested in clipping the content.